# Download private nuget packages from private nuget server

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, nuget, csproj

My .NET 6 project's `.csproj`  has this:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <!-- public -->
  <PackageReference Include="Autofac" Version="1.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="FluentValidation" Version="1.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="1.0.0" />
  <!-- private -->
  <PackageReference Include="Company.Package1" Version="1.0.0" />
  <PackageReference Include="Company.Package2" Version="1.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

The "public" packages are downloaded from the nuget servers, and the "private" ones from our private nuget server.

*But I don't want our private packages' details to be leaked to nuget.*

How do I enforce that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a new nuget feature called ["Package Source Mapping"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-source-mapping).

In the [`nuget.config`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/nuget-config-file#package-source-mapping-section) in the solution's root, I have this:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>

  <packageSources>
    <clear />
    <add key="nuget" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" />
    <add key="private" value="https://www.example.com/v3/index.json" />
  </packageSources>

  <packageSourceMapping>
    <!-- public -->
    <packageSource key="nuget">
      <package pattern="*" />
    </packageSource>
    <!-- private -->
    <packageSource key="private">
      <package pattern="Company.*" />
    </packageSource>
  </packageSourceMapping>

</configuration>
```

Run `dotnet nuget locals --clear all` to clear the cache else the new policy won't apply to packages already in the cache. Then run `dotnet restore`.

Another use case for this feature is to ensure that a package is downloaded from a specific package repository in the case where it exists on multiple repos.